# Image is not being displayed on test server/

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, user-interface, web-deployment

I have a weird problem where an image is displayed in other platforms but the image is not being displayed on the test server. I have thoroughly checked the code and there is no problems with the code. Any ideas or anyone had this issue before?

[Image is displayed like this but only on the test server. The rest are working fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPwm4.png)

Comment: There could be a number of issues, but we can't really help with any of them without seeing your code. The most likely issue is that you've referenced the file incorrectly.

Comment: Files are referenced with crisp perfection. No doubt. Files get displayed in other browser too. It is quite a weird problem.

Comment: @ObsidianAge...I do not have much expertise as you sir but I can assure you that the files are in their respective places. The images are visible in Firefox and IE and not visible only on Chrome when the test server is used and if the files are not referenced properly, it should not be visible on Firefox and IE right?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had issues like this where there were missing mime type mappings on one server vs another.

So the server was not serving the files correctly.

Possibly check your mime type mappings, not sure what server version or otherwise you’re using to help further though.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment mentions that your files are being correctly loaded in other browsers, this isolates your problem as a caching issue.

- First reload your cache by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.
- Second, reload your CSS cache by holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and clicking on the borwser's refresh icon.

This should correctly restore your broken images.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing Empty Cache and Hard Reload.

For chrome, 
1. Open Inspect interface
2. Right click on refresh icon and select the Empty Cache and Hard Reload option

You can also check if your image link is correct. Sometime placing a "/" before the link solves it.

I hope it helps